# How to convert from `func() *int` to `func() interface{}`?

Tags: go

I'd like to have something like the following function:

```
func decorateFn(fn func() interface{}) interface{} {
  decorate()

  return fn()
}

func decorateFnInt(fn func() *int) *int {
  return decorateFn(fn).(*int)
}
```

Using `decorateFn((func() interface{})(fn)).(*int)` doesn't work. Is it possible to convert `func() *int` to `func() interface{}`? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `go 1.18` you can use generics to achieve this - ensuring compile-time type safety and no runtime type assertions:

```
func decorateFn[T any](fn func() T) T {
    decorate()

    return fn()
}

func decorateFnInt(fn func() *int) *int {
    return decorateFn(fn)
}
```

The function `decorateFn`'s type constraint can be inferred at compile-time by inspecting `fn`'s type.

https://go.dev/play/p/AAByiBFRQch

---

***EDIT***: if you are stuck on `go 1.17` and cannot use generics, you can use `interface{}` for the function parameter, but any type decisions must be performed at runtime. You could try a [type switch](https://go.dev/tour/methods/16):

```
func decorateFn(v interface{}) interface{} {
    decorate()

    switch t := v.(type) {

    case func() *int:
        return t()

    case func() *string:
        return t()

    default:
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("unsupported type: %T", v))
    }

}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/gDXTPqA1tXL

Comment: Unfortunately, we're still at 1.17 but it's good to know about this for when we do upgrade.

Comment: `1.18` is backwardly compatible. If you must use `1.17` I've update the answer with one suggestion.